# How to check if the user admin or not?

Tags: laravel

How can I check if the user is admin by using this migration, without using table role.

````
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });```
````

Comment: Just try `Auth::user()->is_admin`  to check anywhere.

Comment: I try this one and it did not work, it's give me this error 
`Trying to get property of non-object`
I'm trying to do this to hide some button from normal user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Blade, you can try this:

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin)
    YOUR BUTTON CODE, IF USER IS ADMIN
@endif
```